# How to remove Ubuntu from dualboot with Windows 10 and install it again?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uninstall

I have recently installed Ubuntu 17.04 on dualboot with Win10, but for some reason it stopped working. Basically when I try to boot Ubuntu a black screen appears and nothing happens.

I would like avoiding reinstalling it if possible, but if it isn't, please tell me how to remove Ubuntu 17.04 and install 16.04.3 in it's place.

Comment: Just download Ubuntu 16.04.3, create a Live USB and install it over Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: A reinstall may not prevent the same problem from re-occurring. There are several possible problems of this sort when you dual-boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Live CD/ USB stick with UBUNTU 16, then boot from the LIVE IMAGE and choose INSTALL UBUNTU

in windows Download the image UBUNTU 16 from here [UBUNTU 16](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute?version=16.04.3&architecture=amd64)

and create the image in USB stick with rufus from here [RUFUS](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)

Fill all the options needed until you get to part in the installation asking what to do with the installation.

Select the last option "something else"

there assuming you have 1 disk "sda" it should have a partition for booting labeled as that eg. efi/boot (you dont touch this)

then a partition for windows NTFS (you dont touch this)

then an "UNKNOWN" partition this belongs to windows too (you dont touch this)

then a "/" ext4 partition labeled ubuntu 17.04, THIS is the partition you want to modify, click the button change, in the little windows that pop ups, select ext4 as system partition, then mark for format and select the "/" symbol as mount point

thats it continue with isntallation  until it finishes.. at reboot you will have ubuntu 16 and windows 10 perfectly fine.

again im assuming you have just 1 disk and that your /home partition is in the same disk.. also asuming that you have a backup of your ubuntu 17 files